# Running bash on python to read from S3 Bucket and saving output

Tags: python, bash, amazon-s3

I'm trying to run the following bash command on python and save that output into a variable. I'm new to using bash so any help will be appreciated.

Here's my usecase I have data stored in an S3 bucket (let's say the path is s3://test-bucket/folder1/subd1/datafiles/)

in the datafiles folder there are multiple data files:

```
a1_03_27_2020_N.csv
a1_04_05_2021_O.csv
a1_07_16_2021_N.csv
```

I'm trying to select the latest file (in this case a1_07_16_2021_N) and then read that data file using pandas

Here's what I have so far

The command to select the latest file

```
ls -t a1*|head -1
```

but then I'm not sure how to
1- run that command on python
2- how to save that the output as a variable
(I know this is not correct but something like

```
latest_file = os.environ['ls -t a1*|head -1'])
```

Then read the file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(latest_file)
```

Thank you in advance again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python replaces most shell functionality. You can do the search and filtering in python itself. No need for a callout.

```
from pathlib import Path

dir_to_search = Path("test-bucket/folder1/subd1/datafiles/")
try:
    latest = max(dir_to_search.glob("a1*.csv"), key=lambda path: path.stat().st_mtime)
    print(latest)
except ValueError:
    print("no csv here")
```

But if you want to run the shell, several functions in `subprocess` will do it. For instance,

```
import subprocess as subp

result = subp.run("ls -t test-bucket/folder1/subd1/datafiles/a1* | head -1",
    shell=True, 
        capture_output=True, text=True).stdout.strip()
```